# Proof of convergence of sequence if every subsequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

> If Every sub sequence of a sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ converges to the same limit, then the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ also converges to the same limit.

This might be in lot of threads but i want to know whether my proof has any flaws.

Given that the sub sequence $\left\{a_{{n_k}}\right\}$ is convergent to a limit say $L$, we have, for a given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists K \in \mathbb{N}$, such that
$$|a_{{n_k}}-L|<\epsilon$$ whenever $n_k \geq K$

Now let us assume that the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ does not converge. So for a given $\epsilon >0$, we can always find $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$|a_n-L|>\epsilon$$ whenever $n \geq n_0$

Now letting $M=max(K,n_0)$ we have $\forall n \geq M$
$$\epsilon <|a_n-L|<\epsilon$$ which is false. Hence a contradiction. Thus the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ should converge.

Is this proof fine?

Comment: Every sequence is a subsequence of itself. So this doesn't need a proof.

Comment: Perhaps, you meant that every **proper** subsequence converges to the same limit instead?

Comment: Actually i saw the theorem proved in both the directions here. It is not specified that the sequence is a proper sub sequence. https://brilliant.org/wiki/subsequences/

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang What is a proper subsequence though? Remove the first element and you get a proper subsequence, so the result is still absolutely trivial. A less trivial result is that if all convergent subsequences converge to the same limit then $a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Anyway, your proof is totally wrong. $a_n$ not converging to $L$ means that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $n_0$ there is some $n\geq n_0$ such that $|a_n-L|\geq\epsilon$. (and not what you wrote)

Comment: That's a good point Mark. So $\epsilon \leq |a_n-L|<\epsilon$ will still be false and hence a contradiction. Is this fine now?

Comment: The problem is not the difference between $<$ and $\leq$. You wrote that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $|a_n-L|>\epsilon$, which is wrong.

Comment: So could you please correct my proof

Comment: It's just totally wrong, you can't simply correct it. Anyway, the statement is trivial as you can see from the above comments. $a_n$ is just a subsequence of itself, hence it converges to $L$.

Comment: @bof You are right, I meant convergence in the extended sense. (i.e including "convergence" to $\infty $ or $-\infty$)